# Canada Study Permit: Please help me write the Explanation letter as to the Source of fund

Tags: canada, student-visa

My DPS 1, DPS 2, DPS 3, DPS 4, FDR 1, FDR 2. My spouse is also my sponsor. She is showing her DPS 1, FDR 1, FDR 2.

As proof of money for the Canada study permit, we are displaying the aforementioned Deposit Pension Scheme (DPS) and fixed deposit receipt (FDR) which were all opened in 2018 or before.

My wife is a doctor, and I am an engineer. We have been maintaining the monthly deposits of all our DPS from THIS SOURCE OF MONEY.

We don't need to do anything because FDR does not require regular installments. After maturity, we will return the entire amount plus interest.

All of the accounts are mentioned in our past 2 years of Income tax assessment as well. My question is, while writing the explanation letter as to the source of funds, should we just mention by emphasizing that we have been maintaining the FDR in our name for five years and providing evidence of our income tax returns and the FDR's growth through interest? Or do I have to also mention who gave the money 5 years ago for my initial main deposits?